# Getting a list of Customers based on sequence of options from another field in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of Customers which have multiple customer groups for
 each customer. For instance  a single customer can have anywhere from
 1 group up to 6 different groups.

The customer table also contains a list of Dependents and a Title for each Dependent.

This is what the table looks like:

```
CustId CustName CustGroup Dependent Title
1 Mike A Sarah SP
1 Mike A Mitch SN
1 Mike A Debra DT
1 Mike A Conner SIL
1 Mike B Sarah SP
1 Mike B Mitch SN
1 Mike B Debra DT
2 Mark A Hamlin BT
2 Mark A Ritchie SN
2 Mark B Hamlin BT
2 Mark B Ritchie SN
3 Carrie A Aaron CR
3 Carie A Simon CR
3 Carie A Crane NP
3 Carrie B Aaron CR
3 Carrie B Simon CR
3 Carrie B Crane NP
3 Carrie C Aaron CR
3 Carrie C Simon CR
3 Carrie C Crane NP
```

I need to get for every customer and for every customer group, a single dependent and title based on priority by CustGroup and Title. There can be multiple Dependents with the same title. In that case, we pull all those dependents.

For CustGroup A, we will first pull a Dependent if their Title is SP. If there is no SP then we pull SN. If there is no SN, then we pull DT. If there is neither of those 3 Titles, then we leave it as blank.

For CustGroup B, we will first pull a Dependent if their Title is DT. If there is no DT, then we pull CR. If there is neither of those 2 Titles, then we leave it as blank.

For CustGroup C, we will first pull a Dependent if their Title is SIL. If there is no SIL then we pull DT. If there is neither of those 2 Titles, then we leave it as blank.

So the expected output should look something like this:

```
CustId CustName CustGroup Dependent Title
1 Mike A Sarah SP
1 Mike B Debra DT
2 Mark A Ritchie SN
2 Mark B <blank> <blank>
3 Carrie A <blank> <blank>
3 Carrie B Aaron CR
3 Carrie B Simon CR
3 Carrie C <blank> <blank>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

edit:

I tried this code and Its close to what I was expecting, but how do i implement blanks?

```
Select * from 
(
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID, CustGroup order by RowNum asc) as TitleRowNum
from
(
Select 
CustId, CustName, CustGroup, [Dependent], Title,
case 
    when CustGroup = 'A' and Title = 'SP'
        then 1
    when CustGroup = 'A' and Title = 'SN' 
        then 2
    when CustGroup = 'A' and Title = 'DT'
            then 3

            when CustGroup = 'B' and Title = 'DT'
                then 1
            when CustGroup = 'B' and Title = 'CR'
                then 2

    when CustGroup = 'C' and Title = 'SIL'
        then 1
    when CustGroup = 'C' and Title = 'DT'
        then 2
else 4 end as RowNum
from GroupContactTest
) table1

) table2

where TitleRowNum = 1
order by CustId, CustGroup;
```

Comment: This looks like an assignment from school. What have you tried?

Comment: What if there is a new Cust Group? What Order will that get? Your table design doesn't lend itself well to this. Is it possible to create a further lookup table which will hold Group, title, sortrank?

Comment: There are only 7 possible CustGroups (A, B, C, K, M, V and Y). Every Customer can have between 1 to 7 CustGroups. Every Customer can also have anywhere from 1 to 10 dependents for each group and some of whom might have the same Title. If need be, we can create tables to hold lookup values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It uses a lookup table where the order is defined

```
CREATE TABLE SortOrder
(
    CustGroup   VARCHAR(1),
    Title       VARCHAR(3),
    SortRank    INT
)

INSERT INTO SortOrder
VALUES
('A','SP',1),
('A','SN',2),
('A','DT',3),
('B','DT',1),
('B','CR',2),
('C','SIL',1),
('C','DT',2)

SELECT  c.*,
        so.SortRank,
        MIN(so.SortRank) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CustId, c.Custgroup) as minRank
INTO    #Dependants
FROM    GroupContactTest c
        LEFT JOIN SortOrder so
            ON c.CustGroup = so.CustGroup AND c.Title = so.Title

SELECT  *
INTO    #HasDependants
FROM    #Dependants
WHERE   minRank = SortRank

SELECT  DISTINCT
        CustId,
        CustName,
        CustGroup
INTO    #DistinctDependants
FROM    #Dependants
WHERE   SortRank IS NULL

SELECT  a.CustId,
        a.CustName,
        a.CustGroup,
        b.Dependent,
        b.Title
FROM    #DistinctDependants a
        LEFT JOIN #HasDependants b
            ON a.CustId = b.CustId AND a.CustGroup = b.CustGroup
```

Comment: Great... Thanks @SEarle1986... That worked beautifully... I got it somewhat working on my end as well but my query looks rather messy. But this, I love... Thanks again.

Comment: No probs, I think it could be tuned a bit more but it does the job!